# Reading from .csv to dataframe from Google Cloud Storage has a bug when ran in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am writing a lightweight ETL function in python.
Have been building it in Google Datalabs for ease of testing.

A part of the workflow includes getting a .csv from Cloud Storage and saving this as a Pandas Dataframe.
This works flawlessly in Datalabs but in Cloud Functions for some reason it starts reading from start of .csv again and appends to the bottom resultin in ~300 duplicated rows.

I tried a few different ways of reading the .csv (pd.read_csv, gcsfs, gsutil, %gcs) and they all work fine in Datalabs reading the correct number of rows but when put in Cloud Functions I get the duplicated rows.
Here's an example with gcsfs:

```
 import gcsfs
 import pandas as pd
 bucket = 'my_bucket'
 gc_project = 'my-project'
 latest_filename = 'my.csv'
 gs_current_object = bucket + '/' + latest_filename
 fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=gc_project)
 with fs.open(gs_current_object, 'rb') as f:
     df_new = pd.read_csv(f)
 print(df_new.shape)
```

I expect the shape to be (15097, 26) which is what I get in Datalabs and how many rows I have in my testing .csv but I get (15428, 26) which is the original .csv with appended duplicated rows from the beginning.

I can use drop duplicates but:
1. Would rather keep the function light, especially since it's within Cloud Functions where I have up to 2GB for it to run
2. The header gets appended too so it starts getting messy since I need to locate it and drop it as well as simply using .drop_duplicates

Anybody run into something similar before?
Anything I can do to fix this bug with reading of the .csv so I won't have to clean up a wrongly read file instead?

EDIT: Here's the full code as within my Cloud Functions instance (obviously removing actual names and personal infos). I try and handle the duplicate rows in this version but am not able to. In fact I get a very strange output where the shape of df_new after me dropping duplicates and top row(duplicate header) shows as (15065, 26) yet when I do df_new.tail() later I get 15098 rows with the last one a duplicate header as well which gives an error when I try and parse dates.

```
def csv_update(request):
    #Moved all imports and isntalls at top
    print('Importing packages and setting variables')
    from datetime import datetime 
    import ftplib
    import gcsfs
    import glob
    from googleapiclient import discovery
    import gspread
    from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import os
    import pandas as pd

    #Defining function variables.
    ftp_usr = "myemail@dotcom.com"
    ftp_pass = "my_unsecured_pass"
    bucket = 'my_bucket'
    gc_project = 'my-project'
    json_original = {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "my-project",
      "private_key_id": "my_id",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\MY KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "my_service_account@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "my_client_id",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/client_email"
    }
    g_spreadsheet_id = 'my_gsheet_id'
    g_sheet_name = 'test'
    dtypes = {'LeadId': 'str'}
    root_dir = '/tmp'
    ftp_path = 'my_ftp_dir'
    date_col_name = 'LeadCreationDate'
    lead_col_name = 'LeadId'

    #Import ftplib. Connect to box (encrypted FTPES) with my credentials and download latest file from crown_reporting. 
    #Get downloaded file from local to crown_test bucket
    print('Connecting to FTP and downloading most recent file to local and then to GS bucket')
    os.chdir(root_dir)
    ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS("ftp.box.com") 
    ftp.login(ftp_usr, ftp_pass) 
    ftp.cwd(ftp_path)
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    lines = ftp.nlst("-t")
    latest_filename = lines[-1]
    print(lines)
    print(latest_filename)
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + latest_filename ,open(latest_filename, 'wb').write)
    ftp.quit()
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)     
    body = {'name': latest_filename}
    req = service.objects().insert(bucket=bucket, body=body, media_body=latest_filename)
    resp = req.execute()
    files = glob.glob(root_dir +'/*')
    for f in files:
        os.remove(f)

    #Read the newest CSV from Google Storage (uses latest_filename from initial FTP download).
    #Had to add .drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True) because some of the lead IDs have multiple rows.
    #Added a custom function to parse the dates as they have 2 different formats and needs to be parsed as datetime in order to sort after appending to df_old later.
    print('Read current csv from GS bucket as df_new')
    gs_current_object = bucket + '/' + latest_filename
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=gc_project)
    col_names=['LeadId', 'Lead_Status', 'MoveType', 'Relo_Status', 'LeadCreationDate',
       'EstServiceRevenueUSD', 'EstServiceCostUSD', 'ActServiceRevenueUSD',
       'ActInsuranceRevenueUSD', 'ActServiceCostUSD', 'ActInsCostUSD',
       'ActServiceMarginUSD', 'CustomerType', 'SaleDate',
       'ControllingOfficeName', 'ControllingCountry', 'ControllingRegion',
       'OriginCity', 'OriginState', 'OriginCountry', 'DestinationCity',
       'DestinationState', 'DestinationCountry', 'UnqualifyReason',
       'LeadControllingCountry', 'URL']
    with fs.open(gs_current_object, 'rb') as f:
        df_new = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=col_names)
    print(df_new.shape)
    print(df_new.dtypes)
    df_new[lead_col_name] = df_new[lead_col_name].astype(str)
    df_new.drop_duplicates(subset=lead_col_name, keep='first', inplace=True)
    print(df_new.shape)
    df_new = df_new[1:]
    print(df_new.shape)                       
    dt_strings = []
    for dt_str in df_new[date_col_name]:
        dt_str = dt_str[:dt_str.find(' ')] 
        dt_strings.append(dt_str)
    print(len(dt_strings))
    def try_parsing_date(text):
        if len(text) == 10:
            return datetime.strptime(text, '%m/%d/%Y')
        else:
            text = '0' + text
            return datetime.strptime(text, '%m/%d/%Y')
    print(df_new.index[(df_new[date_col_name] == date_col_name) | (df_new[date_col_name] == '0LeadCreationDat') ].values)
    print(df_new.tail())
    dt_strings_conv = [try_parsing_date(date) for date in dt_strings]
    df_new[date_col_name] = dt_strings_conv
    print(df_new[date_col_name])
    print(dt_strings_conv)
    df_new.set_index(lead_col_name, drop=True, inplace=True)

    #Authorize for G sheet with JSON. Changed this to JSON parsed dictionary so it's saved within script.  
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(json_original, scope)
    gs = gspread.authorize(creds)

    #Now we can access sheet. NB I had to enable sheets api in console here for this to work. Import pandas and gspread_dataframe. 
    #Set up worksheet via gspread and get the current (old) data in a df. 
    #We also specify a dtype of leadid column as otherwise Pandas thinks it's an integer (first IDs are just numbers). 
    #Had to add .drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True) because some of the lead IDs have multiple rows.
    print('Read current gsheet as df_old')
    sheet = gs.open_by_key(g_spreadsheet_id).worksheet(g_sheet_name) 
    df_old=get_as_dataframe(sheet, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=[date_col_name])
    df_old.drop_duplicates(subset=lead_col_name, keep='first', inplace=True)
    df_old.set_index(lead_col_name, drop=True, inplace=True)
    print(df_old.dtypes)

    #Update any changed rows in df_old with df_new values. Add any new rows (using append and dropping duplicates). Added sort=True to concat because of future warning.
    print('Update df_old with df_new values')
    df_old.update(df_new)
    #print(df_old.shape)
    #df_old.tail(15)
    print('Concat df_old with df_new and drop duplicates')
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_old, df_new], sort=True).reset_index()
    df_combined.drop_duplicates(subset=lead_col_name, keep='last', inplace=True)
    df_combined.sort_values(by=[date_col_name], inplace=True)
    #df_combined.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    #print(df_combined.shape)

    #Connect to gsheet and select worksheet again (in case of timeout, these are commented out as was running fine in tests). Replace all data with newly combined df.
    print('Write updated and concat df_combined to gsheet')
    set_with_dataframe(sheet, df_combined)
```

Comment: I have tried to deploy a function with the same functionality you are describing and the output I am getting is correct for me. Maybe the function is getting triggered more than once hence the incorrect output. Which trigger have you set up for your function?

Comment: I'm getting these unexpected results triggering in testing mode with the triggering event left as the default {}. My function wasn't defined with a parameter originally but because Cloud Functions required it I put a parameter "request" as below which isn't actually used anywhere within that function.

`def my_func(request):`

Answer (score 1):

So all the ways to read from google storage into a dataframe directly produce this bug in Cloud Functions for me. I'd love to get to the bottom of it at some point but for now I need to get my function to work.

In case anybody has a similar issue - I ended up using the below code to store in the local temporary storage first before using pd.read_csv which works fine(note that google.cloud is installed with google-cloud-storage in the requirements.txt):

```
from google.cloud import storage
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
    source_blob_name,
    destination_file_name))
download_blob(bucket, latest_filename, latest_filename)
df_new = pd.read_csv(root_dir + "/" + latest_filename, dtype=dtypes)
```